# Team tagline overflows under the members section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, old-teams

I'm playing with the Teams private beta, and noticed this:

[image]

The full tagline there is `http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq`, but some of it is hiding under my user card.

This is also broken on the 'browse teams' page:

[image]

Comment: Whoops, this definitely looks like a bug. We'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in production.  Thanks for the report!